# MYSQL - Show sum of total work_time but only display results from last updated date_time

Tags: mysql, select, join, sum, subquery

Sorry for the confusing Title. I have been struggling with this query for quite a long time and I will do my best to explain what I am looking for.

I have 3 tables I am trying to pull from. We will call them:

```
headers
details
users
```

The headers table contains two important fields:

```
ref_num
headers_uid
```

The details table has the following important rows:

```
details_uid
headers_uid
work_time
user_uid
disposition
date_time
```

The users table has the following:

```
user_uid
username
```

An example of the details table which contains the majority of the information I need is as follows:

```
details_uid | headers_uid | work_time | user_uid | disposition | date_time
          1 |          10 |     25:00 |        5 |           o | 2013-07-02 12:14:48
          2 |          10 |     10:00 |        7 |           p | 2013-07-02 13:55:37
          3 |          10 |      5:00 |        5 |           c | 2013-07-02 15:04:28
          4 |          12 |      7:00 |        5 |           o | 2013-07-02 15:20:21
          5 |          12 |     12:00 |        7 |           p | 2013-07-02 15:35:27
          6 |          12 |      3:00 |        7 |           c | 2013-07-02 15:40:19
```

What I'm trying to do is display the headers.refnum, sum of total work_time for the unique user for ALL details.details_uids with the same details.headers_uid and only the LAST disposition of the details.headers_uid for the each user. The results must look for a specific date_time (I generally search by > CURDATE() to grab events for today) Also, instead of displaying the user_uid, I will be searching within a WHERE clause by users.username (I have usernames stored in a txt file which is turned into an IN statement).

Ideally, this is what I would like to see:

```
ref_num | work_time | username | disposition |
    A10 |     30:00 |     mike |           c |
    A10 |     10:00 |    james |           p |
    A12 |      7:00 |     mike |           o |
    A12 |     15:00 |    james |           c |
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! I know this will probably involve a good deal of join statements and subqueries and I've been banging my head on the table trying to get it right. I know this would be much easier using php, but sadly, I don't have php access at work yet  (don't ask..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select h.ref_num, sum(d.work_time), u.username, d.disposition
from details d join
     headers h
     on d.headers_uid = h.headers_uid join
     users u
     on d.user_uid = u.user_uid
where d.disposition = (select disposition
                       from details d2
                       where d2.headers_uid = d.headers_uid and
                             d2.users_uid = d.users_uid
                       order by date_time desc
                       limit 1
                      )     
group by h.ref_num, u.username, d.disposition;
```

The key is the `where` clause that selects the last `disposition` for a given set of details records.

Comment: Very nice! It looks like it's working well. Thank you a hundred times over, man! This has been frustrating me for a while now. I never though to look for the disposition in the where clause. My query before had about 3 subqueries and a lot of joins..